# Tkinter text to speech

Tags: python, tkinter, text-to-speech

How do I make this code say a sentence that is in my textbox?
you see I am making a text to speech program that I have for a school project so I need some help taking the input from the text box and making it into sound

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
from tkinter import *
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()


def speak(sentence):
    engine.say(sentence)
    engine.runAndWait() 

speak("Hello World")

window = Tk()
window.title("Text To Speech")
window.geometry('250x125')

lbl = Label(window, text="Input text")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

txt = Entry(window,width=25)
txt.grid(column=0, row=1)


btn = Button(window, text="Speak Text", width=25)
btn.grid(column=0, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: add `command=lambda:speak(txt.get())` in your button constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
from tkinter import *
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()


def speak(sentence):
    engine.say(sentence)
    engine.runAndWait() 

window = Tk()
window.title("Text To Speech")
window.geometry('250x125')

lbl = Label(window, text="Input text")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

var = StringVar()

txt = Entry(window,width=25, textvariable=var)
txt.grid(column=0, row=1)


btn = Button(window, text="Speak Text", width=25, command=lambda: speak(var.get()))
btn.grid(column=0, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks alot this helped but how do I make it so that whenever I click speak text and it says the sentences so it keeps open because when I click speak text it closes the program and says the text